# Reading app.config section name

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection

In console application I'm trying to get `section` key value pair but I couldn't.
There are two ways to do this:

1. [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx)
2. [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx)

But the code below is generating this error: `Configuration system failed to initialize` 
Where am I making mistake?

Here is the code:
`app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="testGroupName">
      <section name="secName" type="TestAssemblyConfigReader.TestConfigReader"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <testGrupAdi>
    <secName anahtar="deger" />
  </testGrupAdi>
</configuration>
```

Config reader class:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace TestAssemblyConfigReader
{
    public class TestConfigReader : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public TestConfigReader()
        {

        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("secName")]
        public string SecName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["secName"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["secName"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console Application:

```
using System.Configuration;
using TestAssemblyConfigReader;

namespace ca_FMC.Turkiye.Lib.SVN
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestConfigReader serviceConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("testGroupName") as TestConfigReader;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello remove mismatch between `testGroupName` and `testGrupAdi`

use this

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="testGroupName">
      <section name="secName" type="TestAssemblyConfigReader.TestConfigReader"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <testGroupName>
    <secName anahtar="deger" />
  </testGroupName>
</configuration>
```